# How to recognise image into text by Autoit?

Tags: image, autoit, image-recognition

Is there a tool to recognise picture into text by Autoit?

I have fixed area on the screen, where some text appears as an image. i need to get its value and save into file.

Pls, don't offer to do it by comparing pixels color.

Comment: So you need help on how to write an AutoIt script that can recognise characters on a given image? How far have you gotten with your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (Optical Character Recognition).

There exist several libraries for this in the [example scripts](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/forum/9-example-scripts/) section of the [AutoIt Forums](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/). Some of the more widely used ones are:

- [Tesseract](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/89542-tesseract-screen-ocr-udf/) (3rd party dll)
- [MODI](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/50608-real-ocr-in-au3-in-a-few-lines/) (requires MS office 2003+)
- [Textract](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/89310-textract-screen-ocr-udf/) (3rd party dll)